# Chromedriver acts weirdly while grabbing data from a certain site

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in association with selenium to parse top 100 names from a website. When I run my script I get a pop up box as a notification/warning.

> What might be the issue here as I've been using the same approach quite some time without any issues in different sites?

[website url](https://propertyspark.com/top-100-real-estate-teams-on-social-media-in-2018/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

def collect_names(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".topcolumn h2"):
        print(item.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://propertyspark.com/top-100-real-estate-teams-on-social-media-in-2018/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    collect_names(driver,url)
    driver.quit()
```

The pop up box:
[image]

The following are the problem signature:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: chromedriver.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5a9904fa
  Fault Module Name:    chromedriver.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5a9904fa
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003c586
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

Comment: I have tried it with Java + Selenium +Chrome it is working fine

Comment: Can you try by changing diff version of driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have upgraded your browser recently, So you also need to upgrade your driver.exe for compatibility.

```
chromedriver    chrome
   2.46            71-73
   2.45            70-72
   2.44            69-71
   2.43            69-71
   2.42            68-70
   2.41            67-69
   2.40            66-68
   2.39            66-68
   2.38            65-67
   2.37            64-66
   2.36            63-65
   2.35            62-64
   2.34            61-63
   2.33            60-62    
   2.28            57
   2.25            54
   2.24            53
   2.22            51
   2.19            44
   2.15            42
```

[Download chrome Driver exe](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)